# IEnumerable comprehension vs returning a Collection Type

Tags: c#, list-comprehension

Is the ever any circumstances, when the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Foobar (Bar bar)
{
    List<Foo> result = new List<Foo>()
    foreach(var Qux in bar.QuxSource)
    {
        Foo item;
        ... //a procudure that is intricate enough not to be clearly repressentable with a LINQ method
        result.Add(item);
        ... //The aforementioned inticate proceduce continues. Possiblily adding more items to result
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is preferable to:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Foobar (Bar bar)
{
    foreach(var Qux in bar.QuxSource)
    {
        Foo item;
        ... //a procudure that is intricate enough not to be clearly repressentable with a LINQ method
        yield return item;
        ... //The aforementioned inticate proceduce continues. Possiblily yielding more items
    }
}
```

I mean the later is clearly wonderful.
With the glory of defered operation, if i only use Foobar(someBar).First(), it doesn't have togenerate the all the returned items.

I see the former used alot, particulary by experienced coders. (Who I guess aren't uptodate with list comprehesions in modern C#).
So is the former patern better undersome cercumstances?
(looking only at library code, targetted at reuse)
I'm thinking maybe when being able to produce the items is dependent on some external resource such as having a file open.
What is the use case foreach?
I'm guess it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example use case is correct, but more generally you'd probably want to adopt the former pattern if:

- The source makes use of a scarce resource and you need to guarantee that the enumerator will be disposed (if you were to begin enumeration on the latter approach and stop in the middle without disposing the enumerator, it would be left open)
- The source should be enumerated as quickly as possible
- You must guarantee that the entire source is evaluated

Answer (score 2):

The first approach - eagerly enumerating the source sequence - is preferred when access to the source sequence is limited in time or should be limited to a narrow time window - i.e. this is the case when retrieving data from a database using a Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities provider. In the second approach you are dependent on the consumer to enumerate your source which may take a much longer time - in general you do not want to keep your database connection open that long.